# Java not finding .so C library for native methods

Tags: java, c, raspberry-pi, shared-libraries, sensors

I've followed [this guide](http://jonisalonen.com/2012/calling-c-from-java-is-easy/) to access two C native methods, but when I call

```
 System.loadLibrary("SensorReader");
```

I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no SensorReader in java.library.path
```

I've followed the guide explaining I have to export the path to have it working temporarily or put the .so library in ld paths. I've even checked for java properties and got this:

```
java.library.path = .
    /usr/java/packages/lib/arm
    /lib
    /usr/lib
```

but even if I put a copy of SensorReader.so in any of those directories (the first one doesn't even exist) nothing changes.
Here is the SensorReader.c code I made the library with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wiringPiI2C.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "HTU21D.h"
#include "SensorController.h"

JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_SensorController_getCurrentTemperature
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    wiringPiSetup();
    int fd = wiringPiI2CSetup(HTU21D_I2C_ADDR);
    double temperature;
    getTemperature(fd, &temperature);
    return temperature;
}

JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_SensorController_getCurrentHumidity
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    wiringPiSetup();
    int fd = wiringPiI2CSetup(HTU21D_I2C_ADDR);
    double humidity;
    getHumidity(fd, &humidity);
    return humidity;
}
```

Executing

```
$ gcc -fPIC -c SensorReader.c -I $JAVA_HOME/include -I $JAVA_HOME/include/Linux
$ gcc SensorReader.o -shared -o SensorReader.so -Wl,-soname,SensorReader
```

returns no errors and the SensorReader.so file is created, I just get the problem when I try to run Java.
I'm not sure but I think the .so library is called on execution and not on compilation, but just in case I've tried both to just execute and compile then execute the code directly on the target Raspberry device and nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently the wrong thing was the missing "lib" before "SensorReader.so" file name.

Changing

```
$ gcc SensorReader.o -shared -o SensorReader.so -Wl,-soname,SensorReader
```

with

```
$ gcc SensorReader.o -shared -o libSensorReader.so -Wl,-soname,SensorReader
```

or maybe just renaming the .so file, then moving it to /lib and executing

```
# ldconfig
```

solved the problem and now Java actually finds the library.

Answer (score 0):

Just a long shot: I have had similar problems trying to load a 64-bit compiled native library with a 32-bit java virtual machine.  You should make sure that both are 64-bit (or 32-bit if it fits better your needs).

In any other case, I would have a second look at the library paths.

Comment: The .so library was compiled on the RPI of course, I guess GCC wouldn't have found libraries such as wiringPI if I did it on my 64x laptop. I'll check what options in first GCC lines mean, maybe it compiles for a different architecture.